# Iterate through a prescribed Google folder to archive spreadsheets in all sub folders

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Link: [Iterate through folders and sub-folders/files and copy spreadsheet data to archive sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31348164/iterate-through-folders-and-sub-folders-files-and-copy-spreadsheet-data-to-archi)

I found the answer in this link really helpful, but have been trying to re-engineer the start so that I can prescribe a folder for it to look in, expand and collect from rather than the whole drive and excluding folders. I've failed! Can anyone suggest how I can do this so that it pulls all spreadsheets from a folder, sub folders and sub-sub folder structure and populates one master sheet - ideally in a completely separate place.

Comment: You need to find a way to get to this foder, and then run the script you found on it. Is the folder at the root of your drive?

Comment: I have added the folder to my drive. It’s one of 17 so I have populated the ‘exclude ids’ for the others. It’s just a bit messy and obviously would need customising for each other user that may benefit from it’s process. Providing the master folder ID would be a much cleaner way.  Also I have a problem with it bringing in sheet data, but then duplicating it again as it finds it within the master file it creates. If I move the master out of the folder I think the exclusions cause a problem as it doesn’t run at all